# Why do I keep getting error: "Error:(20, 23) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Lab1.Person"

Tags: java

The left is what is provided to us by the professor. I am asked to construct a JUnit test. I'm not why I keep getting this error using Java on IntelliJ while doing Junit Testing. Any recommendation?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKelh.png)

[Person.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFVlR.png)

Comment: Yess, I am majoring in computer science right now. I just missed a class

Comment: The error is very vocal, it says you're supplying "John Doe" which is a String object, to a parameter that requires a Person object.

Comment: Hey, next time please paste code as text so that it's easier for everyone to post useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String "JohnDoe" needs to be a Person object. Create a new Person object using a Person constructor. It will **probably** look something like this;

```java
Person person = new Person("JohnDoe"); 

javaBook = new Book("JavaBook", person, 57);
```

Comment: Gotcha! Where exactly would that be placed?

Comment: it would replace "JohnDoe" in the argument to the Book constructor.

Comment: that worked, thank you so much! makes much more sense now

Comment: Yeah no worries eh! Best of luck on your adventures :)